# Google BigQuery extract string from column with regexp_extract

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to extract the app_id from the following string in the column below:

```
&app_id=4.25.9&
```

so anything that starts with `&app_id=` and ends with `&`

Any ideas on how to write this example? The number of characters and symbols may differ.

Comment: like '&app_id%' and like '%&'

Comment: It looks like answer by @Sadiq should solve your issue. If that's the case accept it please.

Answer (score 4):

This should be sufficient:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(your_column, r'\&app_id=(.+?)\&')
```

The app id matching right now `.+?` is a little broad and will match any character, you may want to restrict it further.